# x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match gitlab.internal.com

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci-runner

I have install gitlab on my local machine .

i have installed gitlab runner as well but while registering the runner on the local machine I am getting the following error

I have generated the new certificate but still i am getting the same issue.

x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match gitlab.internal.com

I have tried the the following some solutions but still i am getting the same issue.

https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/OpenSSL_generate_self_signed_cert_with_Subject_Alternative_name_oneliner.html

[How to generate a self-signed SSL certificate using OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-generate-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-using-openssl)

https://devopscube.com/create-self-signed-certificates-openssl/

Comment: Anyone able to solve this issue?